# Using OGR to export 3d polygons from postgis to DXF

Tags: postgis, polygon, ogr, 3d, dxf

Today I tried to export a 3-dimensional geometry out of postgis into a dxf file. After some tests it came out, that I was able to export

- a 3d-linestring which represents the geometry or
- a 2d-polygon which is basically the 3d geometry wih dropped z-values.

but not a closed 3d-polygon.

My environment

- PostgreSQL 9.6, Postgis 2.3.2
- GDAL 2.0.2

Let's create a single polygon and two tables for the ogr-export:

```
--cleanup
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS polygon;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test2;

--create single polygonz
SELECT 
    ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON Z ((0.0 0.0 0.0  ,  10.0 0.0 10.0  ,  0.0 10.0 10.0  ,  0.0 0.0 0.0))') as geom
INTO
    polygon;

--create ogr table with polygon z
SELECT
    1 as gid,
    'Layer 1'::text AS layer,
    'BRUSH(fc:#ff0066,bc:#ff0066,id:"ogr-brush-0")'::text AS ogr_style,
    geom AS geom
INTO
    test1
FROM
    polygon;

--create ogr table with closed linestring z
SELECT
    1 as gid,
    'Layer 1'::text AS layer,
    'BRUSH(fc:#ff0066,bc:#ff0066,id:"ogr-brush-0")'::text AS ogr_style,
    ST_ExteriorRing((ST_Dump(geom)).geom) AS geom
INTO
    test2
FROM
    polygon;
```

And use the following script to export the geometry into DXF:

```
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" test1.dxf PG:"dbname=test3d host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres" -sql "SELECT * FROM test1"
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" test2.dxf PG:"dbname=test3d host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres" -sql "SELECT * FROM test2"
```

Result of test1: 2d hatch

[image: test1.dxf]

Result of test 2: closed 3d polyline

[image: test2.dxf]

Setting

```
 DXF_WRITE_HATCH=NO
```

leads in both cases to a 3d polyline, as shown in the image above.

I also tried to force ogr to create polygonz, using

```
-nlt POLYGONZ
```

which didn't improve the result, that should be a 3d polygon. Any idea how to achive this?

Comment: Please find a picture of the desired result under [https://i.stack.imgur.com/U507f.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U507f.png) as my reputation only allows two image links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

From reading the [source code of the DXFWriter](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/dxf/ogrdxfwriterlayer.cpp), one can see that any polygon with different heights values will be converted to an AcDb3dPolyline entity.

You can have elevation in your DXF if you specify `-zField <column>` in your command, with `<column>` being the column name in your postgis table containing elevation information, but that is not what you want to achieve : elevation is a single property for a polyline, perfect for contour lines but not much else.

The closest DXF entity to a 3D polygon would be 3DSOLID, but the DXFWriter has no support for this entity type as of now.